# Get the expected array with SciPy's Fisher exact test?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

SciPy allows you to conduct both chi square tests and Fisher exact tests.
While the output of the chi square test includes the expected array, the Fisher exact does not.

e.g.:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
obs = np.array(
    [[1100,6848],
    [11860,75292]])
stats.chi2_contingency(obs)
```

returns:

```
(0.31240019935827701,
 0.57621104841277448,
 1L,
 array([[  1083.13438486,   6864.86561514],
        [ 11876.86561514,  75275.13438486]]))
```

while:

```
from scipy import stats
oddsratio, pvalue = stats.fisher_exact([[1100,6848],
[11860,75292]])
print pvalue, oddsratio
```

returns:

```
0.561533439157 1.01974850672
```

The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fisher_exact.html#scipy.stats.fisher_exact) says nothing, and I couldn't find anything online either. Any chance it's possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fisher's exact test (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) doesn't involve computing an expected array.  That's why [`fisher_exact()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fisher_exact.html) doesn't return one.

If you need the expected array, it is the same as that returned by [`chi2_contingency`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html).  If you want to compute it without calling `chi2_contingency`, you can use [`scipy.stats.contingency.expected_freq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.contingency.expected_freq.html).  For example:

```
In [40]: obs
Out[40]: 
array([[ 1100,  6848],
       [11860, 75292]])

In [41]: from scipy.stats.contingency import expected_freq

In [42]: expected_freq(obs)
Out[42]: 
array([[  1083.13438486,   6864.86561514],
       [ 11876.86561514,  75275.13438486]])
```

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Egg all over my face. Don't tell my college statistics professor. :) My approach was to use Fisher's exact to see if there is an effect, and use comparison to the expected value to see the direction. Many thanks!